# Estimate of integral of a nonnegative integrable function via measure of integration domain

Tags: measure-theory

I was trying to solve an exercise in probability theory and I wondered if the following is true:

Let $(\Omega,\mathfrak{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, $A\in\mathfrak{A}$ and $f\in L^1(\mu)$ nonnegative. Then we have that $\int_\mu{\chi_A f \text{d}\omega}\leq \mu(A)||f||_{L^1(\mu)}$.

I tried to find a counterexample on the real line but failed to find one. Maybe there is a really easy one that I overlooked. I tried to prove the inequality but failed to find the right approach. I tried to argue via step functions, but this seems not to work. Maybe one needs to restrict to finite measures to make the above true. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f=\chi_A$. Since $\chi_A^2 = χ_A$, your inequality reads
$$
\mu(A) ≤ \mu(A)^2
$$
so that  $\mu(A)\geq 1$. This is false if $0<\mu(A)<1$.

---

*Remark: This is actually true if $\mu(A)\geq 1$ since in that case
$$
∫_\mu \chi_A\,f ≤ ∫_\mu |f| = \|f\|_{L^1(\mu)} ≤ \mu(A) \,\|f\|_{L^1(\mu)}
$$*